# Landau quantization: Showing that kinetic momenta in the $x$ and $y$ axis are conjugate variables when there is a uniform $B$-field along the $z$-axis

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

I will briefly set up the problem.
Consider a particle of electric charge, $q$, moving in a uniform magnetic field, $\textbf{B}=B\hat{\textbf{z}}$ in three dimensions. We have Hamiltonian,
\begin{align*}
    \hat{H}=\frac{(\hat{\textbf{P}}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{\textbf{A}})^{2}}{2m}
\end{align*}
Since we only have a magnetic field in the $z$-direction, we can choose $\hat{A}_{z}=0$ if our choice $\hat{A}_{x},\hat{A}_{y}$ are independent of $z$. Thus the hamiltonian becomes
\begin{align*}
    \hat{H}=\frac{\hat{{P}}^{2}_{z}}{2m}+\frac{\hat{{\Pi}}^{2}_{x}+\hat{{\Pi}}^{2}_{y}}{2m},\;\;\;\;\hat{{\Pi}}_{i}=\hat{{P}}_{i}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{i}
\end{align*}
Since $[\hat{{P}}_{z},\hat{H}]=0$ the eigenstates of the Hamiltonian are also eigenstates of $\hat{{P}}_{z}$. By writing the Hamiltonian in the form
\begin{align*}
     \hat{H}=\frac{\hat{{P}}^{2}_{z}}{2m}+\hat{H}_{2d},\;\;\;\;\hat{H}_{2d}=\frac{\hat{{\Pi}}^{2}_{x}+\hat{{\Pi}}^{2}_{y}}{2m}
\end{align*}
We only have to determine the spectrum of $H_{2d}$. The idea is that you can first show that $\hat{{\Pi}}_{x}$ and $\hat{{\Pi}}_{y}$ are canonically conjugate (up to a constant of $\frac{qB}{c}$) and you can then show that $\hat{H}_{2d}$ is just the hamiltonian of a quantum harmonic oscillator between these two variables. However when I try and evaluate the commutator between the two variables, I get.
\begin{align*}
    [\hat{{\Pi}}_{x},\hat{{\Pi}}_{y}]&=\left[-i\hbar\partial_{x}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{x},\;-i\hbar\partial_{y}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{y}\right]\\
    &=\left(-i\hbar\partial_{x}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{x}\right)\left(-i\hbar\partial_{y}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{y}\right)-\left(-i\hbar\partial_{y}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{y}\right)\left(-i\hbar\partial_{x}-\frac{q}{c}\hat{A}_{x}\right)\\
    &=(i\hbar)^{2}(\partial_{x}\partial_{y}-\partial_{y}\partial_{x})+i\hbar\frac{q}{c}\left(\partial_{x}\hat{A}_{y}+\hat{A}_{x}\partial_{y}-\hat{A}_{y}\partial_{x}-\partial_{y}\hat{A}_{x}\right)+\frac{e^{2}}{c^{2}}(\hat{A}_{x}\hat{A}_{y}-\hat{A}_{y}\hat{A}_{x})\\
    &=i\hbar\frac{q}{c}\left(\partial_{x}\hat{A}_{y}-\partial_{y}\hat{A}_{x}+\hat{A}_{x}\partial_{y}-\hat{A}_{y}\partial_{x}\right)\\
    &=i\hbar\frac{q}{c}\left(B+\hat{A}_{x}\partial_{y}-\hat{A}_{y}\partial_{x}\right)
    \end{align*}
I don't see any way we can lose the terms $\hat{A}_{x}\partial_{y}-\hat{A}_{y}\partial_{x}$. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply the commutator to a test function:
\begin{align}
\left(\partial_x A_y - \partial_y A_x + A_x \partial_y - A_y\partial_x\right)\psi\\
= \partial_x (A_y \psi) - \partial_y (A_x \psi) + A_x \partial_y\psi - A_y \partial_x\psi\\
= (\partial_xA_y)\psi+A_y\partial_x \psi - (\partial_yA_x)\psi - A_x\partial_y \psi + A_x \partial_y \psi - A_y \partial_x \psi\\
= (\partial_xA_y - \partial_yA_x)\psi\\
= B\psi 
\end{align}

Comment: thank you you legend!